# Jscript code for php page

Tags: php, jscript

I have webpage. I need to create 2 types of view for it. 
Depending of dropdown form I have to choose with content to show.

So, I have created form:

```
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form1">
            <label class="label1" for="viewid">
                View option
            </label>

            <div class="controls">
                <select name="choose_viewid" id="viewid">

                        <option value="var1" >Full view</option>
                        <option value="var2" >Short view</option>


                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

After that I have created php if:

```
if ($_POST[id]= "var1"): {
  include "var1.html";
}


else:
{
  include "var2.html";
}

endif;
```

I have coded js script at the bottom:

```
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

function chooseopt() {
var id= document.getElementById('viewid');

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '',
data:{id:id.value},
});
return false;
};
  </script>
```

But something is wrong. Who can advise needed actions? 
Thank you.

UPD: All this code I have at the same page.

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: Have you called the function chooseopt() in select change.

Comment: Yes. with no result. Maybe I have to reload page? Or use cookie for save stored value of that select?

Comment: Use 'require' instead of 'include', because 'require' will throw exception if any error exist.

Comment: You will have a better time sticking to accessing the DOM via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if ($_POST[id]= "var1"):
```

to

```
if ($_POST['id']== "var1"):
```

Comment: Made it. With no result.

Comment: Strange. var_dump ($_POST['id']); NULL

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `chooseopt` js method when you change option. You can use [jquery handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ou old [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) action.

Comment: I have called, change transcription. But nothing has changed. I suppose that I have no value at default and page are not reload than I have choosen value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript function like this.

```
function chooseopt() 
{
    var objSelected = document.getElementById("viewid");
    var id = objSelected.options[objSelected.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data:{id:id},
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Kumar, unfortunately, nothing.

Comment: Check the console tab in the developer tools in chrome browser, whether any error throws.